# Adding comma while typing in the text box

Tags: jquery, html

I have a text field. I am writing numbers in the text box. While  I am writing I want to add the thousand separator. I found this solution:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name= "name1" id="id1" onclick="addComma('id1');">
<input type="text" name= "name1" id="id2" onclick="addComma('id2');">
```

JQUERY:

```
function addComma(id){
$("#"+id).keyup(function(event) {

  // skip for arrow keys
  if(event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40) return;

  // format number
  $(this).val(function(index, value) {
    return value
    .replace(/\D/g, "")
    .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")
    ;
  });
});
}
```

This only works sometimes. Sometimes it doesn't show the comma at all.

Please tell me what is wrong with my code.

Comment: Define 'works sometimes' ?

Comment: It shouldn't work at all because of the syntax error on line 2. Anyway, it doesn't make any sense to add a keyup handler when the input field is clicked. Just add the keyup handlers on page load.

Comment: I'd suggest you instead do this on the `blur` event. Adding commas as the user types would be unexpected behaviour and could cause confusion.

Comment: Don't use two inputs with same id.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan please can you give me a example

Comment: @JJJ my mistake sorry. I corrected it

Comment: @tenten I added an answer for you

Comment: Line 2 of the JavaScript, not the HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is solution that adding comma while typing in the text box. You need to trigger `keyup` event for every input.

```js
$('input').keyup(function(event) {
    // skip for arrow keys
    if(event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40) return;

    // format number
    $(this).val(function(index, value) {
      return value.replace(/\D/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name= "name1" id="id1">
<input type="text" name= "name1" id="id2">
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you format the input's value on the `blur` event. If you do this as the user types it would be unexpected behaviour and could cause confusion.

Also note that your HTML has duplicate `id` attributes which is invalid, and also has an odd mix of jQuery and JS. You should remove the outdated `on*` event attributes and use unobtrusive event handlers instead. Try this:

```js
$('.foo').blur(function() {
  $(this).val(function(i, v) {
    return v.replace(/\D/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="name1" id="id1" class="foo" />
<input type="text" name="name2" id="id2" class="foo" />
```

Comment: It works only if I don't need to insert decimals.

Comment: @user2342558 https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/make+a+float+to+have+comma+separated+javascript

Comment: I mean by using your code snippet in this answer.

Comment: The question is about adding the thousands separator to the value as it's typed given the OPs use case where decimals do not apply. If decimals was an issue for the OP they would have mentioned it, and most likely not accepted the answer above.